# Access a member of a function of an Observable at runtime

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have this:

[image: nodesc]

`request`, as you can see, is an Observable. Debugging with Chrome's dev tools, I have found that in the `[[Scopes]]` member of the `_subscribe` function there are the values of the arguments that were passed to the Observable.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can access that `[[Scopes]]` member at runtime the same way I'm able to access it using Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: Is this the RxJs Observable type? You should add the appropriate tag so people knowledgeable in this technology will see it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is. Which tag would you suggest?

Comment: The `rxjs` tag, which you already added.

Comment: `[[Scopes]]` is a DevTools feature. It's unrelated to RxJS and - as far as I'm aware - it cannot be accessed by application JavaScript.